# How to insert a file into a database table in SQL

Tags: sql

How can I insert a file into my SQL table? I want to insert txtfile so I can
call it on my web and download it this is my query.

this is my query

```
INSERT INTO [insert].PRequest] [Ticket], ,[umber] ,[Supp] ,[Product] ,[Quantity] ,[DownloadFile])
  VALUES (13,232,'qwewe','Supp',232,C:\Users\casti\OneDrive\Desktop\Download.txt)
GO
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWFFg.png)

Comment: this is my query

INSERT INTO [insert].PRequest]
           [Ticket],
           ,[umber]
           ,[Supp]
           ,[Product]
           ,[Quantity]
           ,[DownloadFile])
     VALUES
           (13,232,'qwewe','Supp',232,C:\Users\casti\OneDrive\Desktop\Download.txt)
GO

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Syntax error. Should be like `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES (v1, v2, v3, ...)`.

Comment: The code you shared is actually saving the path of file now there are two questions whether you want to store path? or whole file and additionally the path you are trying to add have syntax error it should be in single quote like 'C:/path of file'.

Answer (score -2):

You Can not insert file in sql you can only store file path by using that path you can access this file

Comment: Thias may hold true for some databases, but not for all. Also, neither OP nor you stated a DBMS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).